# Hot to modify a relative symlink to be an absolute one?

Tags: linux

I have some (indeed a lot) of symliks in a system which should be absolute but are relative and most of them not working, for instance

/etc/systemd/system/xdm.service -> usr/lib/systemd/system/display-manager.service

when it should be

/etc/systemd/system/xdm.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/display-manager.service

I know I could delete the symlink and create it again, but I want to do it in an automatic way as there are a lot of them

I can obtain all missing symlinks with find / -xtype l

But I don't know an easy way to make the symlink absolute... there is a way to make the reverse with symlink -c

Comment: The first example isn't relative so much as broken. If you want a heuristic to identify broken symlinks and fix them we'll either need you to state what that heuristic should be or we'll need quite a number of examples to review

Comment: "do it in an automatic way" Write a simple script to delete it and create it again? Than run script with `-exec` in `find`? And have a look at `readlink -m` etc.